# Arrange multiple plots into one grid

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to arrange 49 plots into a 7x7 grid but the plots will not plot correctly using `qplot`.

```
a <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)
b <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)
for(m in 1:7)
{
  for(n in 1:7)
  {
    #Q4. Assigning variables for moving averages
    assign(paste("ma_a",m,"b",n,sep=""),c())
    for(i in 1:1000)
    {
      .GlobalEnv[[paste("ma_a",m,"b",n,sep="")]] <- c(.GlobalEnv[[paste("ma_a",m,"b",n,sep="")]],mean(rgamma(i,a[m],b[n])))
    }

    #Plotting moving averages
    plot(1:1000,.GlobalEnv[[paste("ma_a",m,"b",n,sep="")]]
         ,type="l"
         ,xlab="X"
         ,main=paste("Moving Average at","Shape=",a[m],"Scale=",b[n])
         ,ylab="Average"
    )
  }
}
```

When like this the plots work correctly but after trying to arrange them into a grid, I realized I had to use `qplot()` in order for `grid.arrange()` to work. It says I cannot use a numerical vector so I have tried using a data frame with 2 columns, first being 1:1000 and the 2nd being the moving average but this will still not plot correctly and just gives a grey box covering all of the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using grid based graphics system, you can use `par()` to arrange your figures.
See if this works:

```
a <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)
b <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)

par(mfrow=c(7,7), mar=c(2,2,2,0))

for(m in 1:7)
{
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, what is the mar=c(2,2,2,0) doing?

Comment: `mar` adjust the margins (the areas of the plot left for text and axis labels). They are specified starting from the bottom - first number is bottom, second - left side, third - top, fourth - right side.

Comment: Also, is there anyway to give a title to the group of plots, and instead of a 7x7 grid is there anyway I can do 7 graphs per page?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do all of those things. But it is not something I can convey over a short comment. try `par(mfrow=c(1,7))` to get a column of 7 plots.

Comment: Yeah I think I will be able to separate them myself, Thanks very much.